# jQuery Form Action Change Not working

Tags: jquery, forms, jqueryform

Anybody has any idea why this snippet is NOT working in newest version of Firefox? (working correctly ex. in Chrome).

```
$("select[name='action']").live('change', function()
    {
        $(this).closest("form").attr('action', $(this).val());
        alert($(this).closest("form").attr('action'));
        //$(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
```

**Edit**
It's not working in IE8 too. Weird.

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="#">
 <fieldset>
  <select style="width:95px" name="action" class="action">
   <option>Select</option>
   <option value="/user/account">Preview</option>
   <option value="/user/account/edit">Edit</option>
   <option value="/user/account/upgrade">Upgrade</option>
  </select>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Please also post the HTML. Also please describe the symptoms in detail.

Comment: @Mark Eirich - Symptoms? In Chrome alert() shows correct action, based on selection, in FF it shows #, in IE nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a naming-conflict, give the select another name.

The form has an attribute "action" and a member "action" (the select itself, because it's name is "action").

The alert should give you in FF an `[object HTMLSelectElement]`, `form.attr('action')` points here onto the `<select/>` instead of the action-attribute of the form, which you like to access.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the conflict.